# Image width goes beyond the column on Bootstrap 4 by default

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 alpha and my image which is in the same limited column as the text is going beyond the allowed width by default. Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmpPGO

[image]

Setting a `width: 100%` on img fixes the problem, however this default behavior does not sound right.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try a class="img-responsive"

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify the content as it’s coming from my underlying blog generator engine. Is there a way to use it without the .img-responsive (or .img-fluid)?

Comment: Are you able to fix this with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `img-fluid` class for responsive images in Bootstrap 4...

`<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Restless_flycatcher04.jpg" class="img-fluid" />`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmpVLj

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify the content as it’s coming from my underlying blog generator engine. I thought about doing `#id .img {width:100%; height:auto}`